# What are the Correct parameters to create object storage account

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to create an object storage account using the following command:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @Object-Storage-Account-create.json https://<userid>:<apikey>@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder
```

JSON payload is

```
{
"parameters": [
    {
        "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Hub",
        "quantity": 1,
        "packageId": 206,
        "prices": [
            {
                "id": 16984
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

but getting the error `{"error":"Bad request","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_WebService_BadRequest"}`

Can you please let me know the correct parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the last "**}**" in your **Object-Storage-Account-create.json** file?

because your template works fine for me, and the issue seems that is something is missing in your template, perhaps the last "**}**", can you make double check please?

```
{  
   "parameters":[  
      {  
         "complexType":"SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Hub",
         "quantity":1,
         "packageId":206,
         "prices":[  
            {  
               "id":16984
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```